# Flex: Hide border if two column in a row

Tags: css, flexbox, css-selectors

I have a grid system where can be situation 3 or 2 items in a row. I wanted to place a separate border style for column items using CSS.

---

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

---

CSS

```
.container {
    display: flex;
.item {
    border-right:2px solid red;
}
.item:last-child{
    border-right:0px;
}
```

---

What I need is to remove the border style of the second item if two items in the row

[image: What I need is to remove the border style of the second item if two items in the row]

Comment: Can you please explain what you want to do? its not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last-child doe's not works because that targets the last child in your container.
A hacky solution would be to add a border left and hide it with a negative margin if it is the first element...

Not sure if it fits your requirement but the fallowing snipped generates a similar result

```css
.container-wrapper {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: -12px;
}

.item {
    border-left: 2px solid red;
    min-width: 180px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px -2px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="item">7</div>
      <div class="item">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, Seems a good hack. But having a dynamic element in a minus value could hide some content as we don't have control of the content.

Comment: No it won't hide the content since the negative margin is equal with the border and the margin on the element. This means that the content will be always visible...

Comment: Let me try again freshly, and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: BTW the idea is that you hide the mark on the left... The key element is the overflow hidden on the .container. You can combine it with the other solution which draws the separator using the after pseudo element.

Comment: Thank you Zsolt, It helped to solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {display: flex;}
    
.item {
    background: #eee;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    padding: 15px;

    margin:0 10px; 
    position: relative;
}
    .item::after {content: ' '; width: 2px; height: 100%; background-color: red; position: absolute; left: -10px; top: 0;}  
.item:first-child{
    margin-left: 0;
    
}
.item:first-child::after{
    display: none;
    
}   
    
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)  {
        .item {width: calc(100% / 2);}
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the try Jone, In my case, Screen size is not a matter, There could be more items in a container or less. in my case. I have set a maximum of three columns depending on items. if there are fewer items than two-column. so not screen size.

Comment: When I tried your code, I get a border for second-row items.